# SWT - Can we make button using SWT that can refresh our eclipse Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Can we make a button using SWT in eclipse that can refresh our Project made in eclipse ? if yes then how ? thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a plugin to create your button and hook it where you need (see . then,

```
Button button = ...
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelection(SelectionEvent e) {
        ResourcePlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("myProject").refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
    }
}
```

See also https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_should_I_use_refreshLocal%3F

However, there is already the "Refresh" context menu in Project Explorer for that. I don't really get why a new button would help. Also, if you know that you sometimes need to refresh a project, why don't you do it anyway when you detect it can be useful without requiring user to click on a button?

Comment: Thank you for the solution . I need to refresh the project when one wizardPage(Dialogue) is open . When wizardPage is open we cant click on our project.